# How to set the xaml DesignInstance attribute in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

I want to activate IntelliSense for ViewModel binding in my Xaml-Views. If i put the following line in my article view, I see the viewmodel properties in intellisense.

```
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewmodel:ViewModelArticle}"
```

But I don't want to do this manually in all my views. I want to do it in Code.

I have realized generic inheritance in all my xaml views like this

```
public partial class ArticleCard : ArticleCardBase
{
    public ArticleCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public abstract class ArticleCardBase : CardBase<ViewModel.ViewModelArticle> { }

public abstract class CardBase<TData> : UserControl, IView<TData>, ICardBase where TData : VMCardBase
{
    private CardRibbon _ribbon;
    ...
```

So I have the concrete Type of my ViewModel in my generic base class for every View, and this works also with the designer.

Now I try to set the DesignInstanceExtension like this (to get the Extension i installed nuget "ICSharpCode.WpfDesigner"):

```
    public CardBase()
    {
        this.Initialized += CardBase_Initialized;

        var markup = new ICSharpCode.WpfDesign.XamlDom.DesignInstanceExtension(typeof(TData));
        markup.ProvideValue(new Target(this, Window.DataContextProperty));
   }

    public struct Target : IServiceProvider, IProvideValueTarget
    {
        private readonly DependencyObject _targetObject;
        private readonly DependencyProperty _targetProperty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Target"/> struct.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetObject"></param>
        /// <param name="targetProperty"></param>
        public Target(DependencyObject targetObject, DependencyProperty targetProperty)
        {
            _targetObject = targetObject;
            _targetProperty = targetProperty;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == typeof(IProvideValueTarget))
            {
                return this;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        object IProvideValueTarget.TargetObject { get { return _targetObject; } }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        object IProvideValueTarget.TargetProperty { get { return _targetProperty; } }
    }
```

This Target-Object was just a try to use the MarkUpExtension ProvideValue method, but this is not working.

Does anybody know, how to do this in Code?

Comment: I don't think you understand what IntelliSense is. It has nothing to do with your code, it's a feature from the IDE. The xaml tag is just something the IDE uses as help and is ignored by the actual code. I don't think it's possible to set a default, or specific datacontext they way you want, unless the IDE adds that feature.

Comment: I understood IntelliSense. I hope for an answer such like: "Yeah, thatsa possible, but not that easy. write an own xaml extension like this..."... I'm sure this can work - a xaml or visual studio extension would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d:DataContext` design-time attribute is only available in the context of XAML and the designer. You cannot set it programmatically in C#. There are no CLR types that correspond to `DesignInstance`, `DesignData` and the rest of the design-time attributes.

Comment: Yeah, i was afraid of that. I will wait a few days and then i will mark this as the answer... :-|

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DesignerProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerproperties?view=netframework-4.8) class to check whether the application is in design mode or not:

```
public abstract class CardBase<TData> : UserControl, IView<TData>, ICardBase where TData : VMCardBase
{
  public CardBase()
  {
    this.Initialized += CardBase_Initialized;

    this.DataContext = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
      ? new DesignModeViewModel()
      : new ViewModel();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats not what i need. I want to simulate the d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewmodel:ViewModelArticle}" - Line in my c# base class code. This line writte in Xaml gives me intellisense. I dont want to set the real dataContext.